# Phonegap Plugin Error during initialization

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, ripple

Hey guys i'm workin on an app, which check whether a user has logged in the app before or not. I use phonegap in combination with jquery-mobile. But if i test my app with ripple with the following code:

```
    var SaveUserStatus = function() { 

    }

    SaveUserStatus.prototype.check = function(succes,fail) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(function(args) {
        success(args);
    }, function(args) {
        fail(args);
    }, 'SaveUserStatus', 'getUserStatus', '');
}

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin('saveUserStatus', new SaveUserStatus());
    PluginManager.addService("SaveUserStatus","net.testing.plugins.SaveUserStatus");
});
```

I get always following error messages:
**"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasResource' - phonegap-1.0.0.js:936"** and **"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addConstructor' - plugin.js:17
"**
Has anyone the same error or see the error, this would be nice because i going crazy with that!

Answer (score 1):

Comment out

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

in your HTML-File.

For further informations read the comment by Dan Silivestru http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/forums/6/topics/50

Comment: The link is now dead, unfortunately.